# Problem using enzyme with connected components in an attempt to simulate click

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I can not do click simulation with enzyme and connected components. I've tried some solutions, but nothing without success.

the project:

[https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test/blob/master/src/pages/**tests**/formDocumentos.test.js](https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test/blob/master/src/pages/__tests__/formDocumentos.test.js)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper.find may be returning array of elements. Try to access elements by index and then simulate click.

```
var test = wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click');
```

Comment: I tried and returned

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you test with mount instead of shallow wrapper.

Comment: sorry, but with mount it would be possible to pass store? how would the composition be until the click call?

Comment: Yes. Mount just gives you additional test for component did mount hook.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wrap your component with to higher order components (`connect`,`withFormik`). To reach your actual component `FormDocumentos` you need to use `dive` twice.

```
 wrapper = shallow(
      <FormDocumentos
        match={INITIAL_STATE.match}
        values={newDocumentos}
      />,
      { context: { store } },
    ).dive().dive();
```

Comment: yes, I'm using formik along with the FormDocuments component. I put two dive as suggested but the feedback I got now was:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined
```

Comment: First you could `console.log(wrapper.debug())`, this will show you the actual rendering. Next if you see the `button` there you could try wrapper `wrapper.find('button')at(0).simulate('click');`. If you don't see the button you have to use `dive()` again until you see the button in the logging